# POST Ajax request getting timout

Tags: ajax

I am getting "Gateway Time-out" error in my browser while making post ajax request as below:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/templatemanager/fileupload.html',              
  data: formData,
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
  type: 'POST',
  success: function(data){
    alert ('done');
  },
  error: function(jqhdr, textStatus,errorThrown){
    alert (errorThrown);
  }
});

The error thown message is "Gateway Time-out".

Please let me know, how to rectify this issue.
Whether, i should increase the tomcat http connector tiemout or ajax timeout?
```

Comment: Gateway Time-out error persist in server side scripting not in ajax.. so please check server side  scripting code. Mostly due to third party API integration but API not responding on time then this error is cause.

Comment: i have java code logic which parse the file upload and insert the record in data base. This is the special case where my file has more records since then my ajax showing error.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a "POST" to a HTML file. I'd try setting setting 'type' to "GET".

(Or, is the file supposed to be a PHP, since it is presumably about file uploading?)

Comment: This post was working for some use cases, only failing when file uploaded has more data and my java code which insert the parsed record into DB taking time.

Comment: "only failing when file uploaded has more data "

Then I'd suggest setting the timeout variable in the ajax to a high value so the server can take time processing it rather than the (too short) time it gets right now. It seems like that is the issue.

Comment: I tried setting the timeout as 3 minute ( timeout:180000 ) but the ajax failing as its not bother of timeout parameter.

Comment: can you give us some examples of when it did work vs. when it didn't work?

Comment: Hi Lucas, my ajax request working perfectly when there is less records to be processed and inserted into data base, when records are increasing say more than 5000 then only AJAX start throwing error on UI and i can see the logs on server still getting rotated and once the logs are stopped i can see correct number of records are there in DB , but Ajax has already shown me error on UI.